# Graphical historical test duration with CI for GitHub

Tags: github, continuous-integration

Is it possible in Travis (or another free CI for opensource project in GitHub) to have a graph that display the evolution of test duration ?

I found an example of what I expected with TeamCity. But it's expensive for a personal project.

[image]

My project is in C++ with CMake and tests are run with CTest.

I would like to avoid to make a script to download the build log, extract duration test printed in log, create a database and finally display all in a graph.

UPDATE:

I found my happiness with Jenkins and the plugin xUnit ([#21633716](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633716/producing-ctest-results-in-jenkins-xunit-1-58)). I know it's not exactly what I asked at first (it's not fully integrated with GitHub) but Jenkins looks really good for what I need.