# How to call properly xUnit on Jenkins under Linux

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, xunit, ctest

I followed the answer of Alastair Harrison for [the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633716/producing-ctest-results-in-jenkins-xunit-1-58) 
but Jenkins gives me a lengthy output of errors.

The relevant part of my code goes as follows:

```
    stage('Testing'){
        steps{
            dir('chidotu'){
                dir('build'){
                    dir('tests'){
                        sh 'ctest -D ExperimentalTest --no-compress-output'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

post {
always {
  // Archive the CTest xml output
  archiveArtifacts (
    artifacts: 'chidotu/build/tests/Testing/**/*.xml',//In this path a xml file is generated
    fingerprint: true
  )

  xunit (
    testTimeMargin: '3000',
    thresholdMode: 1,
    thresholds: [
      skipped(failureThreshold: '0'),
      failed(failureThreshold: '0')
    ],
  tools: [CTest(
      pattern: 'chidotu/build/tests/Testing/**/*.xml',
      deleteOutputFiles: true,
      failIfNotNew: false,
      skipNoTestFiles: true,
      stopProcessingIfError: true
    )]
  )


  // Clear the source and build dirs before next run
  deleteDir()
}
```

When Jenkins executes the pipeline, I get:

```
100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 20

Total Test time (real) =   1.68 sec
[Pipeline] }

[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)

[Pipeline] archiveArtifacts// this comes from the line concerning to: archiveArtifacts (

Archiving artifacts
Recording fingerprints
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
[Office365connector] No webhooks to notify
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'skipped' found among steps [archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, cmake, cmakeBuild, cpack, ctest, deleteDir, dir, dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients, envVarsForTool, error, fileExists, getContext, git, input, isUnix, junit, library, libraryResource, load, mail, milestone, node, office365ConnectorSend, parallel, powershell, properties, publishHTML, pwd, readFile, readTrusted, resolveScm, retry, script, sh, sleep, sshagent, stage, stash, step, svn, timeout, timestamps, tm, tool, unarchive, unstash, validateDeclarativePipeline, waitUntil, withContext, withCredentials, withDockerContainer, withDockerRegistry, withDockerServer, withEnv, wrap, writeFile, ws] or symbols [all, allOf, always, ant, antFromApache, antOutcome, antTarget, any, anyOf, apiToken, architecture, archiveArtifacts, artifactManager, authorizationMatrix, batchFile, booleanParam, branch, brokenBuildSuspects, brokenTestsSuspects, buildButton, buildDiscarder, buildingTag, caseInsensitive, caseSensitive, certificate, changeRequest, changelog, changeset, checkoutToSubdirectory, choice, choiceParam, cleanWs, clock, cloud, cobertura, command, configFile, configFileProvider, credentials, cron, crumb, culprits, defaultView, demand, developers, disableConcurrentBuilds, disableResume, docker, dockerCert, dockerfile, downloadSettings, downstream, dumb, durabilityHint, envVars, environment, equals, expression, file, fileParam, filePath, fingerprint, frameOptions, freeStyle, freeStyleJob, fromScm, fromSource, git, headRegexFilter, headWildcardFilter, hyperlink, hyperlinkToModels, inheriting, inheritingGlobal, installSource, isRestartedRun, jdk, jdkInstaller, jgit, jgitapache, jnlp, jobName, label, lastDuration, lastFailure, lastGrantedAuthorities, lastStable, lastSuccess, legacy, legacySCM, list, local, location, logRotator, loggedInUsersCanDoAnything, masterBuild, maven, maven3Mojos, mavenErrors, mavenMojos, mavenWarnings, modernSCM, myView, newContainerPerStage, node, nodeProperties, nonInheriting, nonStoredPasswordParam, none, not, office365ConnectorSend, office365ConnectorWebhooks, overrideIndexTriggers, paneStatus, parameters, password, pattern, permanent, pipeline-model, pipelineTriggers, plainText, plot, plugin, pollSCM, preserveStashes, projectNamingStrategy, proxy, queueItemAuthenticator, quietPeriod, recipients, remotingCLI, requestor, run, runParam, schedule, scmRetryCount, scriptApprovalLink, search, security, shell, skipDefaultCheckout, skipStagesAfterUnstable, slave, sourceRegexFilter, sourceWildcardFilter, sshUserPrivateKey, stackTrace, standard, status, string, stringParam, swapSpace, tag, text, textParam, tmpSpace, toolLocation, unsecured, upstream, upstreamDevelopers, usernameColonPassword, usernamePassword, viewsTabBar, weather, withAnt, zfs, zip] or globals [currentBuild, docker, env, params, pipeline, scm]
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:176)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11865.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:157)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:133)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:129)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:44)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.delegateAndExecute(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:133)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.runPostConditions(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:732)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:380)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:378)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.runPostConditions(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:731)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.each(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:2030)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.each(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:2015)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.each(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:2056)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.runPostConditions(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:727)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.executePostBuild(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:706)
at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1768.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatch(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:55)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.item(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:45)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6252.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$$Lambda$74/1840606671.call(Unknown Source)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Finished: FAILURE
```

As far as I understand. Jenkins is mounted in a linux server, I don't know if the solution goes in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be that you just don't have [xUnit Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin) installed. So, you need to install this plugin and the pipeline should be running correctly.